# Multiple git repositories in a path

Tags: git, projects

I got a project ("myproject"), managed with git. Inside the project there is another project ("a_node_module"), managed with git, too.

```
myproject
├── .git
├── .gitignore
└── node_modules
    └── a_node_module
        └── .git
```

The .gitignore file contains:

```
node_modules
```

Is this okay or can this cause conflicts? (confusing IDE's, for example).

The reason why I want to do it this way is: it saves a lot of time, while the node module is required in the main project, so I can work on both projects together, and don't need to synchronize the sub project all the time.

Comment: Did you try? If yes, did you encounter some problems?

Comment: I'll try it soon - a "yes" and a "no" is like no answer

Answer (score 2):

As long as the inner repository is either:

- a git submodule
- added in the '.gitignore' of the outer repository

You should not have problems

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing it by myself.

- `git` itself does not have any problems with it.

With the IDE (PHPStorm) I can open files of both projects, but features like

- adding new files to git
- highlighting code changes
- diff
- etc.

are only available for the files of the main project.

Answer (score -1):

Git cannot contain inner project unless its glink or submodule.

It can cause errors.

Add you subproject as submodule to avoid such a collision.

[image]